# Changing association type to aggregation results in diamond symbol on wrong side

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect (EA) 9.3 I do the following on a UML class diagram:

- Select an Association link between two classes
- Right-click and choose Advanced / Change Type from context menu
- Change type from Association to Aggregation and click OK

What I find is that the diamond symbol for an aggregation is drawn on the wrong side (the destination side).
Is this a known bug? Is there a easy workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In enterprise architect the lines are drawn from part to whole, so source is without the diamond.

If you want to change it:

Go to Tools-> Options -> Links

And set the "Draw Aggregations Reversed" Option

[image: Option]

Comment: I am confused. UML Defines that the diamong symbol MUST be on the source side. Does EA not follow that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: EA draws aggregations and compositions with the diamond at the connector's target end. The above setting does not change this behaviour, it simply reverses the connector when drawn. In EA 10 the quick link aggregation and composition menu items are both split into "to whole" and "to part" items for clarity.

Comment: Farrukh you are mistaken. UML does not define that the diamond should be on a specific end.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change an Association to an Aggregation. Instead, open the Association's properties and go to either the Source Role or Target Role page and set the "Aggregation" value to "shared" or "composite".

Comment: In EA 9.3 I cant see any way to edit the properties of the Association. I select it and right-click but see no menu selection that goes to its properties.